# Creating elevation profile from line feature, DEM and also polygon layer inside graph, using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, elevation, topography, graph

I´m new to ArcGIS Pro.

I have:

1. DEM,
2. Line feature (river) and
3. A vegetation vector layer (polygons).

I would like to make a profile from this line feature (the river), and if it is possible to show in this profile the different vegetation types it passes through.

I have been using “Exploratory 3D Analysis” >  “Elevation Profile”, which creates a profile which is exactly what I want, but is it possible in any way to add the vegetation layer into this?

If it is not possible, is it then possible to export the profile as a picture without the grey frame around the profile (for editing in GIMP, or another program?

I can change the colour of the elevation line and the colour inside the graph, but not the frame around it (in “properties”).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a profile graph using the workflow as described [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/3d-analyst/interactively-create-a-profile-graph-with-digitized-lines-on-a-surface.htm) and not via the Exploratory 3D Analysis. You will have better control over the look of the graph through it properties.

As for symbolizing adjacent riparian vegetation, without further information it's unclear what it is you want to do.  I suspect its beyond the capabilities of a profile graph but you can [export](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/share-a-chart.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_49225AE42B284CC3A3D921EC451AAE2B) a chart and then draw on top of that?